# Notice of access to the photos on an iOS device automatically displays the operating system or of the app is to be deployed

Tags: ios

my application accesses the photo section of the iOS device. Access authorization is automatically displayed by the operating system or do I have to implement it with the code (I'm using iOS6).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will get shown automatically, you just have to handle to potential outcomes (like when you don't get access) and act accordingly. Note that the once the access is denied you won't get access not then and not in the future, so you have to handle the error accordingly (for example pointing the user to the system settings in order to grant you access).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was a question that I had. Thank you.

Comment: If my answer was helpful you should mark it as accepted, that way anyone who has a similar question knows this answer to be the suitable one.